# php combine ssh2.sftp and zip file wrappers

Tags: php

Is there a way to combine the ssh2.sftp:// and zip:// file wrappers? I know it's possible for some of the other wrappers such as `compress.zlib://php://input`

Here's what I've tried:

```
$handle = fopen("zip://ssh2.sftp://{$session}/myfile.zip#myfile.csv",'r');
```

and

```
$handle1 = fopen("ssh2.sftp://{$ssh_session}/myfile.zip",'r');
$handle2 = fopen("zip://{$handle1}",'r');
```

(I didn't expect the 2nd to work)

Comment: You can combine using your first format, but you need to get the streams the right way round

Comment: Reversing it doesn't work either: `$handle = fopen("ssh2.sftp://zip://{$session}/myfile.zip#myfile.csv",'r');`

Comment: @Peavey: No, I ended up downloading to a tmpfile and then using zip://. Also, I've since found ssh2.* handlers are crap and I'd recommend using [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) instead.